# Cannot Get-ADComputer using a filter that contains a variable and a wildcard

Tags: powershell, ldap

I'm having trouble attaching a wildcard (the `*` character) to the end of a variable that contains a string in both a `-Filter` and a `-LDAPFilter` for `Get-ADcomputer` in PowerShell.

I've tried a few solutions that I'll highlight below that I couldn't get to work.  `$compName` will be the variable I'm trying to add a wildcard to.

1. The first thing I tried was a simple concatenation on a regular filter because it's just a string, shouldn't I be able to add the wild card on the end?

`$compArray += Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -eq "$compName' + '*"' -SearchBase "OU=Office,DC=workplace,DC=org" -ResultSetSize 5000 | Select -Exp Name;`

2. The second thing I tried was putting two `*` on either side of my variable because I saw this seems to be a common thing for wild card searches but alas that didn't seem to provide a solution either.

`$compArray += Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -eq "*$compName*"' -SearchBase "OU=Office,DC=workplace,DC=org" -ResultSetSize 5000 | Select -Exp Name;`

3. Since neither of those solutions worked I decided to switch to `-LDAPFilter`.  The first thing I tried in LDAP was another concatenation.

`$compArray += Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter '(name=$compName' + '*)' -SearchBase "OU=Office,DC=workplace,DC=org" -ResultSetSize 5000 | Select -Exp Name;`

4. What I tried after that is similar to attempt number 2, I put the `*` around the entire variable but that didn't seem to work either.

`$compArray += Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter '(name=*$compName*)' -SearchBase "OU=Office,DC=workplace,DC=org" -ResultSetSize 5000 | Select -Exp Name;`

5. As to not get too repetitive I also tried separating the `$compName` from the rest of the string in the first four attempts, so we'll use the first as an example here.

`$compArray += Get-ADComputer -Filter 'Name -eq "' + $compName + '*"' -SearchBase "OU=Office,DC=workplace,DC=org" -ResultSetSize 5000 | Select -Exp Name;`

6. The sixth try is where things get more interesting but I'm also pretty sure I didn't implement this method properly.  I came across [this post on techncet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/544d57d3-0fca-4fc9-8b78-271f606a00f2/issue-with-wildcard-search-in-getadcomputer?forum=winserverpowershell) and thought I'd give it a try.

`$compArray += Get-ADComputer -Filter *|  where {$_.name -match "$compName[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"} -SearchBase "OU=Office,DC=workplace,DC=org" -ResultSetSize 5000 | Select -Exp Name;`

A couple of things to note with the above method, it wasn't very clear to me where `$_` came from so that might be the cause of some issues.  The other is that since this method uses some form of regex I thought I could search for what I'm trying to use a wildcard for which is a series of 4 digits but that didn't seem to help.

7. I also  tried using a `where-object` too that failed me as well.

`$compArray += Get-ADComputer where-object 'Name -like "*$compName*"' -SearchBase "OU=Office,DC=workplace,DC=org" -ResultSetSize 5000 | Select -Exp Name;`

As I alluded to above I'm not sure why any of my attempts didn't work hence I'm asking the question here.  **What am I doing wrong when trying to `Get-ADComputer` with a variable and a wildcard?**  I only need one of them to work so no one needs to figure out the issues with all of them but if you'd like to feel free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing a comparison with `-eq` and a wildcard, use the `-like` operator. `-eq` looks for an exact match, and doesn't handle wildcards; `-like` does:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '*$ComputerName*'" -SearchBase ...
```

Comment: @BlueBarren Also note the Double Quote outer, Single Quote inner. This formatting produces the best results for the AD filters.

Comment: Ah I didn't realize `-Filter` was so picky when it came to stuff like that.  On the note of quotes my other filters work fine, does it really make that much of a difference?

Comment: @BlueBarren Filters are dependent on the provider, so they can behave differently. With the AD cmdlets, especially using wildcards, double then single works in most all scenarios.